# Swift Realm. How to put 3 millions objects in database

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I make offline dictionary app. And now I convert dictionary file to realm database.

Convert function:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dictionary", ofType: "dsl") {
        do {
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
            let myStrings = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

            for (index, row) in myStrings.enumerated() {

                if(row.containsChineseCharacters)
                {
                    let firstWord = CNDict()
                    firstWord.word = row
                    firstWord.pinyin = myStrings[index+1]
                    firstWord.translate = myStrings[index+2]

                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.add(firstWord)
                    }
                }
            }
            print("The task end.")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
     }
```

When I try to convert the dictionary immediately, the database file becomes a lot of gigabytes and crashes around the middle

Splitting the dictionary in parts is not an option, because there are about 3 million lines. It will take very much... (realm plugin crashes)

I need help on how to add as many values to the database with our crashes.

Comment: What is the context, does each user have a 3 million element dictionary on their phone that will be converted into their own realm database when they update? Any possibility to pre-populate the database on the server?

Comment: Please share `CNDict` Realm model to see if it's correct. Another thing you have `Fatal error: Index out of range`, because of possible increment of last`index+1` and `index+2`.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. In general when posting a question, it's good to include details so we understand the use case. For example, what is a *dictionary file*? What's the structure of your data? As mentioned in a prior comment, index+1 doesn't have any context so we don't know what that is. What's a CNDict? 3M lines is quite a bit and may overload the device, can you bring the data in chunks instead of reading it all at once? Maybe process the file line by line? Please take a moment and review: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your file is large and at this point, you load it into the memory:

```
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
```

And then you double the memory footprint here:

```
        let myStrings = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

So my guess is that you received out of memory signal from the system.

Instead of loading into the memory all the data and than double it, you can use `lazy` collection. It will read and parse the line only when it needed for writing. It will not load all lines at once. One downside of lazy collections in Swift is that they could not provide all the functions that we get used to.

Here the full code for playground that solves your issue. You could and maybe should optimize some parts of it, but anyway it just showing how it could be done with `lazy` collection. (I changed some names, but it's still what you want).

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    var containsOneSymbol: Bool {
        return contains("1")
    }
}

extension Character {
    var isNewLine: Bool {
        let string = String(self)
        let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

        return !set.isDisjoint(with: CharacterSet.newlines)
    }
}


/// Add Object subclass for Realm
@objcMembers
final class CNDict {
    dynamic var word = ""
    dynamic var pinyin = ""
    dynamic var translate = ""
}

final class ModelWriterWrapper {
    private let bufferCapacity = 3
    private var buffer: [String] = []
    init() {
        buffer.reserveCapacity(bufferCapacity)
    }

    func proccess(line: String) {
        guard buffer.count == bufferCapacity else {
            assert(buffer.count < bufferCapacity, "Buffer failer count: \(buffer.count)!")
            buffer.append(line)
            return
        }

        if let firstLine = buffer.first, firstLine.containsOneSymbol {
            let dict = CNDict()
            dict.word = firstLine
            dict.pinyin = buffer[1]
            dict.translate = buffer[2]

            print("Ready for writing into DB \n word: \(dict.word) pinyin: \(dict.pinyin) translate: \(dict.translate)")
        }

        buffer.removeFirst()
        buffer.append(line)
    }
}

let data = stride(from: 0, to: 100_000, by: 1).map { "Line number \($0)\n"}.joined()

var line: String = ""
let myLines = data.lazy.map { char -> String in
    line.append(char)
    guard !char.isNewLine else {
        defer { line = "" }
        return line
    }

    return ""
}.filter { !$0.isEmpty }


let databaseWritter = ModelWriterWrapper()

myLines.forEach {
    databaseWritter.proccess(line: $0)
}
```

If have any questions regarding the code, please ask.